# Retrieving of coordinates from google maps and search

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I know there is a way to retrieve the coordinates by clicking on the map, using specifically 
            document.getElementById("lonTb").value=point.x;
            document.getElementById("latTb").value=point.y;

Firstly, i have a html file namely MapToolKit.html, a mapGPS.js and a mapSearch.js.

how do i input the coordinates returns into the js? I just need to be able to click the map for coordinates, not neccessary the search returns.
Here's the file which i uploaded. http://www.mediafire.com/?0minqxgwzmx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GEvent.addListener

```
var long;
var lat;
GEvent.addListener(map,"click", function(overlay,latlng) {
  long = latlng.lng();
  lat = latlng.lat();
});
```

this will put the longitude in the `long` variable and the latitude in `lat` variable

Comment: i tried to implement it into my mapGPS.js and it doesn't seem to be able to work, im not quite sure whats wrong with it